# Работа с JavaScript из Java

Tags: javascript, java, android

Здравствуйте. Возник вопрос и я даже не знаю как правильно загуглить. Мне нужно каким то образом работать с javaScript на странице, на уровне нажать кнопку\выбрать поле в селекторе. Пните в нужную сторону.

Comment: Вы либо решаете какую-то более общуу задачу, либо недостаточно конкретно её описываете. В любом случае, стоит добавить подробностей о том, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: А чем эта задача не конкретна? Как по мне заголовок и текст вопроса полностью отражают суть и в пояснении не нуждаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Принцип думаю ясен

```
webView.loadUrl("url");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {      
         String javascript = "javascript:var para = document.createElement(\"script\");para.textContent = \"document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value = '23';\";document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(para);";
         view.loadUrl(javascript);
    }
});
```

Comment: Для андроид 5+ следует использовать метод:

`view.evaluateJavascript(yourScript);`